# Unable to compare std::ifstream to an std::string

Tags: ifstream

My code is stuck in an infinite loop because the content of `ifile` is not matching the label.

During debugging I noticed that the content of `ifile` is the entire file as a string.

```
void Experiment::read_moveTo(ifstream* ifile, string label) {
    string temp;

    while (temp.compare(label) != 0 and ifile) {
        *ifile >> temp;

       if (ifile->eof()) {
            cout << "Read error: Could not find label '"
                 << label << "' while reading parameter file '"
                 << parameterFile << "'" << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I want the `ifile` content to match the label and exit pointing to that address.

Comment: We need more information than this. Show us the content of the file.

Comment: Also, show us how you create the stream pointer and send it to the method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the stream failed to perform an extraction (due to whatever was in the file), so `std::ios_base::failbit` was set in the stream state. This means any subsequent I/O operations on the stream will simply do nothing.

Your only condition for breaking out of the loop is the initial condition where you check the pointer:

```
while (temp.compare(label) != 0 and ifile)
//                                  ^^^^^
```

and where you check for an end-of-file status:

```
if (ifile->eof())
```

Assuming the input failed because of something prior to this function being called (either the file couldn't be opened or an invalid read was performed beforehand) both of these conditions fail to adequately check the stream. The first condition simply checks the pointer for a non-zero value, which is true if the pointer wasn't set to `NULL` (which I'm assuming here). The second condition is always false because the stream can no longer perform any operation that would cause `std::ios_base::eofbit` to be set.

You need to dereference the pointer in the while loop so the stream state can be checked:

```
while (temp.compare(label) != 0 and *ifile)
//                                  ^
```

This will fix the infinite loop, but you still have to give up more detail about what's inside the file and how you create and pass the stream to fully solve this issue.